# how to write a custom rake task for RSpec?

Tags: ruby, rspec2

In my Rake file:

```
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'

desc 'Default: run specs.'
task :default => :spec

desc "Run specs"
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new do |task|
    task.pattern = "**/spec/*_spec.rb"
    task.rspec_opts = Dir.glob("[0-9][0-9][0-9]_*").collect { |x| "-I#{x}" }.sort
    task.rspec_opts << '-r ./rspec_config'
    task.rspec_opts << '--color'
    task.rspec_opts << '-f documentation'
end
```

In rspec_config.rb

```
RSpec.configure {|c| c.fail_fast = true}
```

My file structure:

```
|-- 001_hello
|   |-- hello1.rb
|   `-- spec
|       `-- hello_spec.rb
|-- 002_hello
|   |-- hello2.rb
|   `-- spec
|       `-- hello_spec.rb
|-- 003_hello
|   |-- hello3.rb
|   `-- spec
|       `-- hello_spec.rb
|-- Rakefile
`-- rspec_config.rb
```

when rake task will run it will do the operation sequentially on the above file structure.
How to ensure that if '001_hello' fails then it should not run '002_hello'?

Currently it run on reverse order ie. '003_hello' then '002_hello' then '001_hello'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to modify the task pattern to get files to run in a particular order. For instance:

```
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new do |task|
  task.pattern = Dir['[0-9][0-9][0-9]_*/spec/*_spec.rb'].sort
  task.rspec_opts = Dir.glob("[0-9][0-9][0-9]_*").collect { |x| "-I#{x}" }
  task.rspec_opts << '-r ./rspec_config --color -f d'
end
```

This will run all files matching `###_*/spec/*_spec.rb` in alphabetical order.

Comment: Thanks Thomakos, but if I do what you say then the following error occurs : `<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- hello1 (LoadError)
 from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
 from /home/suvankars/RnD/rspec/001_hello/spec/hello_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'`

Comment: You're missing the files from your load path then - this has nothing to do with ordering. I'll updated my post with the answer on how to add those files as well. Ideally you should add these files to your path in some other way, or you should include them with a relative path to the file in your specs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand if the execution order is actually a problem for you.

Anyway, if the application should exit upon error, why don't you just raise an exception?

**EDIT**
Since the execution order is meaningful to you, I think that

```
task.rspec_opts = Dir.glob("[0-9][0-9][0-9]_*").collect { |x| "-I#{x}" }.sort
```

won't do what you expect.

Probably the file are then included in no particular order, so you should programmatically invoke each file individually and check it.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment. But execution order is very important to me. I want something similar to ruby koans. I have three test case if first one fails then it will not run second and third. After fixing first one it will run rest of all, if second one fail then third one will not run and so on.

Comment: Using that particular code it invoke all file in proper sequence `@rspec_opts=
  ["-I001_hello",
   "-I002_hello",
   "-I003_hello",
   "-r ./rspec_config",
   "--color",
   "-f documentation"],` but they are executing in reverse order. How to change the order  of execution ?