# Running multiple specs defined by input file

Tags: ruby, rspec, rake

Given that I have an external file that will control which specs are being ran.

```
control.xls
test_id|description|file_path           |run
1      |Test 1     |./spec/test1_spec.rb|yes
2      |Test 2     |./spec/test2_spec.rb|no
```

I have a method that reads the file and returns an array of file_paths.

I want to use that array of files to run the spec, it can be through rake or command line.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. You could simply write a custom rake task that would contains the code that read your file. You can then call the RSpec Rake task for each of the file ([RSpec::Core::RakeTask](http://rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/RakeTask)), something like this (for the structure, this is untested code !) :

```
require 'rake/testtask'

namespace :test do
  task :spec do
    test_files = ...
    test_files.each do |test_file|
      RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new do |task|
        task.rspec_opts = test_file
      end
  end
end
```

You also have an example there : [how to write a custom rake task for RSpec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397728/how-to-write-a-custom-rake-task-for-rspec)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I understand what you explained, but is not working yet.

Answer (score 0):

Found on another place on stackoverflow: [Whats is the replacement for spec_files in RSpec::Core::RakeTask ? Does pattern accept array of files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815762/whats-is-the-replacement-for-spec-files-in-rspeccoreraketask-does-pattern)

So it accepts an Array of files, I was using FileList to pass the files and was only running the last spec.

Thanks for the input Martin